# Find function not working in all sheets as expected

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a code to find a value (say B) that is closest to the input (say A and A is a number) using Xlookup worksheetfunction. I also need the cell address of the returned value B so that i can make a range for further processing.

It works fine with the xlookup function but I have error while trying to use the find function to find the value

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   Dim rng1, result_rng1 As Range
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim nowsheet As Worksheet
   Dim start_rng, end_rng As Range
   'Set start_rng = Nothing

   '''active sheet is the sheet containing input value A in
   lat_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   MsgBox (lat_row)
   For i = 2 To lat_row
       ''Name of the sheet in xlookup shall look for value A
       Set ws = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) & "_Orcaflex_Depth")
       ''' last row of ws
       last_row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
       'MsgBox (last_row)
       ''Range in ws in which A shall be searched
       Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(last_row, 2))
''''        Set result_rng1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 3), ws.Cells(last_row, 3))
       ''return the value in the cell as d1
       d1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value, rng1, rng1, , -1)
      ' MsgBox (d1)
       ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 16) = d1
   Next i
     '''this loop shall find the cell address of the cell containing the value that was discovered using the previous loop
   For i = 2 To lat_row
       ''Name of the sheet in xlookup shall look for value A
       Set ws = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) & "_Orcaflex_Depth")
       Set nowsheet = Sheets("Result_Offset")
       ''' last row of ws
       last_row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
       'MsgBox (last_row)
       Set results_rng1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(last_row, 2))
       Set start_rng = results_rng1.Find(what:=nowsheet.Cells(i, 16).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
       MsgBox (Cells(start_rng).Address)
   Next i
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, use `start_rng.Address` instead of `Cells(start_rng).Address`. Then, you should firstly check if `Find` returned a range: `If not start_rng is Nothing Then ...`. If `Find` did not return a cell range you have to use more arguments: `SearchOrder`, `SearchDirection`, `LookAt` etc. `Find` **keeps the last chosen parameters when last used, even if you manually used it**... You can find its necessary arguments [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find). And use a single iteration, please. You have to use `Find` immediately after obtaining `d1`.

Comment: Note that `Dim start_rng, end_rng As Range` will only delclare `end_rng As Range` but `start_rng As Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable or it is `Variant` by default: `Dim start_rng As Range, end_rng As Range`! • Also you have non-declared variables! Make sure you declare every variable properly and use `Option Explicit`.